# How to read memcpy struct result via a pointer

Tags: c++

I want to copy a struct content in memory via `char* pc` the print it back but here I have an exception (reading violation)

```
struct af {
        bool a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint16_t c;
    };

int main() {

        af t;
        t.a = true;
        t.b = 3;
        t.c = 20;

        char* pc = nullptr;

        memcpy(&pc, &t, sizeof(t));

        std::cout << "msg is " << pc << std::endl; // here the exception

        return 0;
    }
```

then I want to recover data from memory to another structure of same type.
I did `af* tt = (af*)(pc);` then tried to access to `tt->a` but always an exception.

Comment: you can copy a struct to some memory pointed to by a `char*`, but `pc` does not point anywhere.

Comment: does not point to a valid `char` at any rate. `nullptr` is a relatively safe and testable place to park a pointer until you have something you can point it at. Every processor or I've used reserves a block of memory around `nullptr` as unusable so it can easily trap errors where you accidentally operate on a `nullptr`.

Comment: You may want `char pc[sizeof t];` instead - and then `memcpy(pc, &t, sizeof t);`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @user4581301 many µc actually have the trap table or some other important settings at address 0 (though technically nullptr does not have to be address 0 ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate memory before you can copy something into it. Also, `pc` is already the pointer, you need not take the address of it again. Moreover, the byte representation is very likely to contain non-printable characters. To see the actual effect the following copies from the buffer back to an `af` and prints its members (note that a cast is needed to prevent `std::cout` to interpret the `uint8_t` as a character):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct af {
        bool a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint16_t c;
    };

int main() {
    af t;
    t.a = true;
    t.b = 3;
    t.c = 20;

    char pc[sizeof(af)];

    std::memcpy(pc, &t, sizeof(t)); // array pc decays to pointer to first element

    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(af); ++i){
        std::cout << i << " " << pc[i] << "\n";
    }
    af t2;
    std::memcpy(&t2, pc,sizeof(t));
    std::cout << t2.a << " " << static_cast<unsigned>(t2.b) << " " << t2.c;

}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/9n43dvb69):

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
1 3 20
```

Note that I replaced the output of `pc` with a loop that prints individual characters, because the binary representation might contain null terminators and `pc` is **not** a null terminated string. If you want it to be a null-terminated string, it must be of size `sizeof(af) +1` and have a terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: technically `&pc` points to the bytes of the pointer itself, which should be 4/8 bytes on x86 / x64, so it should be enough to hold the contents of the structure (so its not undefined behaviour). however then you would need to use `af* tt = (af*)(&pc);` to access it again. (but OP probably didn't intend to do this)

Comment: @Turtlefight right. Initially there was more wrong stuff in the answer because I was confused about `nullptr` vs `&pc`.